# Why doesn't nth-of-type work on an image wrapped in an a tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am attempting to style a specific image in a series using the nth-of-type function but it seems to break when I wrap images in an a tag. If I only use images it works fine.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o87oyfrx/1/

```
.row2 img:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid green;
} 

<div class="row2">
    <a href="http://abcnews.go.com/"><img src="http://abcnews.go.com/assets/images/navigation/abc-logo.png" /></a>
    <a href="http://abcnews.go.com/"><img src="http://abcnews.go.com/assets/images/navigation/abc-logo.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't `:nth-of-type()` work on an image wrapped in an `<a>` tag?

It would, but since you're using `:nth-child()`, and not `:nth-of-type()`, I'll address that instead (though the answer is pretty much the same, regardless).

The problem you're facing is that your selector is selecting the wrong element, because the `<img>` elements within `.group3` are individually wrapped in `<a>` elements, so `img:nth-child(2)` can't match anything; had you tried [`img:nth-child(1)`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o87oyfrx/5/), or [`img:first-child`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o87oyfrx/6/), you'd see that both `<img>` elements would have been successfully selected because they're both `:nth-child(1)` and `:first-child` within their respective parents.

So, to select the second `<img>` element that appears within `.group3`, we need to select via its parent, the `<a>`:

```
.row3 a:nth-child(2) img {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o87oyfrx/4/).

It's important to note that `:nth-child()` does *precisely* what it tells you it does (in its very name); it selects an `<img>` element *if* it is the `:nth-child()` of its parent. As all the `<img>` elements are individually wrapped in `<a>` elements, none of those `<img>` elements can be matched.

That means to select the second `<img>` we need to select the only image (or potentially all the images), that are held within the actual second-child of the `.row3` element, which is the `<a>`.

References:

- [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Comment: Thank you, this explains it perfectly.