# Can We use nested child selector or ">" in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to distance my `img-2.png` around `margin-left: 100px`. I can do it if I only add a new class like this `img-margin-left` but I want to challenge myself to use a child selector in CSS or this symbol `>` but can I use this selector as a nested class?

This is my code:

```css
#paham-download {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}

#paham-download .left {
  text-align: left;
}

#paham-download h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3b73c5;
}

#paham-download p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #1d3962;
}

#paham-download .img-fluid {
  max-width: 200px;
}

#paham-download .row>.row>img:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="paham-download">
  <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="col col-6 left">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Sub Title</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/utility/img-1.png" alt="img-1" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="col-6">
            <img class="img-fluid img-margin-left" src="../assets/utility/img-2.png" alt="img-2" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-6">
      <img src="../assets/dashboard/img-3.png" alt="img-3" width="640" height="720" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the line that I want to make it nested selector:

```
#paham-download .row > .row > img:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

This is what I got right now:

[image]

This is what I want to achieved with nested selector or at least without adding any new class

[image]

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897913/why-doesnt-nth-of-type-work-on-an-image-wrapped-in-an-a-tag) that has a really detail explanation, but I can't implement it well.

Comment: :nth-child selects the second child, not the second occurance of an element. You only have one child. try `#paham-download .row > .row:nth-child(2) > img`

Comment: you can but your html doesn't have the tags you describe in css for example you have no `.row > .row`, you only have `.row > .col > .row`

Comment: the other problem as @cloned observed is you put the `nth-child` on the wrong element, it should actually be `#paham-download .row .row:nth-child(2) > img` or `#paham-download .row > .col > .row:nth-child(2) > img`

Comment: What's the point of having `col-6` inside `col-3`

Comment: Thankyou for the response, I tried @cloned style but nothing changed and it still the same as the first image

Comment: can you make a fiddle @RakishFrisky, we don't know which image is which

Comment: yeah it's still too early. you also only have 1 row. See the posted answer, you need the 2nd-child of an element where there actually are 2 of them (your columns.) 
Please also check Roko's comment, your markup doesn't really make any sense. Don't put a col-6 directly inside col-3

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan at first I think when I have `col-3` it will start again from `col-12` so i just think if I want make it half I add another `col-6` for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
#paham-download > .row .row .col-3:nth-child(2) img {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer it works for me! so i just realize that if you want to select class you can just use `:nth-child()` selector and if you want to select element such as `p`, `img`, or `div` you can use `:nth-of-type()` selector